# Como mudar uma TEXTO para NUMERO no Python

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook

Estou com uma base de dados no Python onde todos os valores dela são strings (texto), porém eu quero numerar essas strings

A questão é.
Tem uma coluna que tem 10 tipos de texto diferentes, e então, eu preciso numera-los, de modo que eu consiga se referenciar a cada um deles usando um número.

Exemplo:
A coluna tem esses valores nela
"Permanent",
"Temporary",
"Seasonal",
"Contract".,..

Quando eu numerar essa coluna de strings, eu apenas seleciono um número específico para cada nome.
Por exemplo:
"Permanent" = 1
"Temporary" = 2
"Seasonal" = 3...

Espero que tenham entendido.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/137387

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenta ajustar os dados pra uma lista, pois vou usar dictionary comprehension (compreensão de dicionário):

Digamos que tenhamos o seguinte código:

```py
coluna = ['Permanet', 'Temporary', 'Seasonal', 'Contract']
```

você pode fazer uma compreensão de dicionário.
Mas o que seria uma compreensão de dicionário?

é basicamente uma forma de criar objetos iteráveis de maneira mais rápida.

caso queira estudar mais sobre compreensões de dicionário em python, recomendo que veja esse [link](https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/dict-comprehensions-no-python).

Mas então, você basicamente faz isso daqui

```py
indexes = {item: numero for item, numero in enumerate(coluna, start=1)}
print(indexes)
>>>Saida: {1: 'Permanet', 2: 'Temporary', 3: 'Seasonal', 4: 'Contract"}
```

daí você pode pegar os valores usando:

```py
print(indexes[1])
>>>Saida: Permanet
print(indexes[3])
>>>Saida: Seasonal
```

se quiser fazer ao contrário também dá:

```py
indexes = {item: numero for numero, item in enumerate(coluna, start=1)}
print(indexes)
>>>Saida: {'Permanet': 1, 'Temporary': 2, 'Seasonal': 3, 'Contract': 4}
# Forma de acessar tais itens
print(indexes['Permanet'])
>>>Saida: 1
print(indexes['Seasonal'])
>>>Saida: 3
```

Mas então, para que serve o enumerate, e o start?
o enumerate, como o próprio nome diz, enumera, assim dentro de um for ele coloca um número a tal item, a medida que for iterando, já o start, serve pra definir o número que ele vai começar a enumerar, se não colocar ele automaticamente enumera apartir de 0, coisa que na maioria das vezes não é bom, principalmente para uma tabela, já que é bom que em qualquer tipo de informação apresentável (mesmo que não mostre para ninguém), seja possível analisar as informações com mais facilidade, e uma lista começando a partir de 0 pode confundir um pouco na hora :/

Comment: Provavelmente a pergunta se refere a [DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) onde o AP quer criar uma [série](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) removendo os valores duplicados da coluna em questão e então substituir no dataframe os valores dessa coluna pelos índices da série. Porém como a pergunta está mal formulada não deveria ser respondida.

Comment: Augusto, muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: fui eu que comentei ;---; o cara ele só corrigiu uns ruídos de comunicação